# Pandas change column value based on other column with lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to replicate a simple Excel function in pandas, with no success. Haven't tried np.where() yet, as I want to learn lambda functions and rely less on imports where possible.

Function to replicate:

```
=+IF([@[Coupa Type]]="freeform","Freeform","Structured PO")
```

Lambda I tested and works:

```
lambdatest = lambda x: f"{x} is even" if x % 2 == 0 else f"{x} is odd"
```

Lambda for pandas which is not working:

```
test = raw[["Coupa Type", "Structured Pos"]]
test["Structured Pos"] = test.apply(
    lambda x: "Freeform" if test["Coupa Type"] == "freeform" else "Structured PO"
)
```

Error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My guess that it's trying to evaluate the entire column instead of line by line, how do I fix this?

Comment: First, are you sure you are on the right axis on the apply, by default it goes vertical and not horizontal, you need to put axis = 1 for a row wise apply. Second thing i'm noticing, in your second lambda function, you use test and not x, maybe that's your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I this you need to add `axis=1` to your `apply()` call, to make the lambda function be executed for each row, instead of for each column, which is the default:

```py
test["Structured Pos"] = test.apply(
    lambda x: "Freeform" if x["Coupa Type"] == "freeform" else "Structured PO",
    axis=1,
)
```

(You also need to use `x["Coupa Type"]` instead of `test["Coupa Type"]` in the Lambda function, as I've done above.)

---

A more efficient solution for this case though would be to do something link this:

```py
test["Structured Pos"] = test["Coupa Type"].map({"freeform": "Freeform"}).fillna("Structured PO")
```

...because `map` replaces all values in the series that are keys in the dictionary with the values of the dictionary, and values in the Series that aren't in keys in the dictionary, it replaces with NaN, so you can use `fillna` to supply the default.